# Update subdocument not working nodejs mongodb express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have this endpoint:

```
restaRouter.route('/lists/:id/')
    .post(function(req, res) {
        db.Restaurant.update({_id: req.params.id}, { $push: { reviews: req.body }}, function(err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json(doc);
        })
    });
```

When I do a post, it is supposed to find a document like this using the `_id`. The `_id` is dynamically generated:

```
{
  "_id": "571616e420cac41111e90ecf",
  "title": "Yep",
  "address": "Somewhere",
  "about": "Everything",
  "reviews": [
    {
      "name": "My name",
      "email": "email@gmail.com",
      "message": "My message"
    }
  ]
}
```

and push an item to the reviews field as a subdocument.

`req.body` looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "email": "foo@bar.com",
    "message": "myFoo bar"
}
```

Do I know a json object is what is hitting the endpoint? Yes. A `console.log(req.body)` confirms.

At the moment, when I post, the response I get back is

```
{
  "ok": 1,
  "nModified": 0,
  "n": 0
}
```

Nothing was modified then. What am I doing wrong? I doubt it has anything to do with this, but I'm using mongojs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your query you have to use `{_id:ObjectId('myobectID')}`

So with your exemple :

```
db.Restaurant.update({_id: ObjectId(req.params.id)}, { $push: { reviews: req.body }}, function(err, doc) {
...
}
```

**mongojs specific**

Since the OP mentions `mongojs`, same above could be done with:

```
db.Restaurant.update({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id)} ...
```

Comment: Fixed. Its kinda weird I missed that. Thanks

Comment: If you could accept the answer my reputation will be thankful :)